# Use localhost:4040 on Windows

Tags: localhost, ngrok

I want to know how can I access my localhost folder and go to some file like https://localhost:4040/index.html without using any external software. I just want to know the folder where I have to copy index.html so I can access this link.

I am using ngrok but it returns a 404 error. I tried putting the index.html in the same directory as ngrok.exe

Comment: You need to have a web server, or something acting as one, running on your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/docs) allows you to expose a web server running on your local machine to the internet.

## 1. localhost

If you just want to access your `localhost` folder, you don't need `ngrok`.

Either way, the first step is to run a web server — a one-liner on [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

If you have Python 3:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

If you have Python 2:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

The file is now accessible at http://localhost:8000/index.html.

## 2. ngrok

If you want to access your `localhost` on another device, run ngrok:

```
ngrok http 8000
```

You should see a line like:

```
Forwarding    https://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:8000
```

The file is now accessible at **https://`92832de0`.ngrok.io/index.html**.

Comment: But where will I have to save the index.html for the ngrok one

Comment: Wherever you run the Python command from - yes, even in the `ngrok` one.